# Emails repeatedly sent at each Cron run

Tags: cron, rules

In my project i am using the [Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to schedule the sending of emails to some users on my site.

At cron run, the scheduled emails are sent as expected.

However I found out that at each subsequent cron run, the mails are repeatedly sent to users.

When i checked the "queue table" in my database, i found out that at each cron run, the "expire value" of the rules_scheduler_task is reset into the current date.

Is this the cause of the problem?

Please how can this be resolved? I want emails to be sent only once.

Comment: Not sure what is causing this; how often are you running the cron? Can you replicate the issue on a clean install?

Comment: The cron is being run every hour, but i do not think it has anything to do with the frequency of cron run. I am yet to try on a clean install.

Comment: how are you tagging the emails as sent?

Comment: Please can you provide information on tagging emails as sent?

Comment: Please include a copy of your rule that ***schedules*** the sending of those eMails. I'm 99% sure that the explanation for your issue is that there is something wrong in that rule, ie the Rules Event you're using, or any of the Rules Conditions in it.